# Cannot access all elements given in the database

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the code. It perfectly displays all of the elements that I want. But when I click "enroll" it enrolls only one element for any chosen element. What is the possible problem?

Here's the code:

```
if(array_key_exists("id", $_SESSION)) {

    include("connection.php");
    $query = "SELECT * from `classes`";       

    echo '<div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true"> ';

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    $results = array();

    $rows = array();
    $queries = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        array_push($rows, $row);
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($rows); $i ++) {

        $name = $rows[$i]["name"];
        $start_time = $rows[$i]["begTime"];
        $end_time = $rows[$i]["endTime"];

        $price = $rows[$i]["price"];
        $places = $rows[$i]["placesAvailable"];

        if (array_key_exists("enroll", $_POST)) {
            $queries[$i] = "UPDATE `users` SET sectionID = ".$rows[$i]["ID"]." WHERE id = ".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_SESSION['id'])." LIMIT 1";

            $results[$i] = mysqli_query($link, $queries[$i]);             
        }

        echo '
            <div  class="card">
                <div id = "section" class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                            '.$name.'
                        </a>
                    </h5>
                </div>

                <div id="collapse" class="collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                    <div class="card-block">
                    '.$name.'
                        <p> <strong> Time: </strong>'.$start_time.' - '.$end_time.' </p>
                        <p> <strong> Price: </strong>'.$price.' </p>
                        <p> <strong> Places available: </strong>'.$places.' </p>
                        <form action="" method = "post">
                            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name = "enroll" value = "Enroll">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>            
        ';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: You only update 1 item (user) in your update query. `WHERE id = ".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_SESSION['id'])`. I am not sure I understand exactly what you want to do, but it seems to me you will need to post some data in your form. Can you explain a bit more i detail what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want the users to enroll to the course. I have a page with the list of courses and a button 'enroll' to each of them. After clicking the button next to the specific course, I want to update the database saying that current user enrolled to the course. How can I modify my code to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic was not quite correct because you were not sending the desired course id to the script together with the submitted `enroll` button. 
I have adapted your code to do so. 
This logic will only work if your user/student should enroll in only one class at the time.

```
if(array_key_exists("id", $_SESSION)) {

include("connection.php");

        if (array_key_exists("enroll", $_POST)) {
            $query = "UPDATE `users` SET sectionID = ".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["ID"])." WHERE id = ".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_SESSION['id'])." LIMIT 1";

            mysqli_query($link, $query); 
        }


    $query = "SELECT * from `classes`";


    echo '<div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true"> ';

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        $name = $row["name"];

        $start_time = $rows["begTime"];

        $end_time = $rows["endTime"];

        $price = $rows["price"];

        $places = $rows["placesAvailable"];



        echo '

            <div  class="card">
                <div id = "section" class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                            '.$name.'
                        </a>
                    </h5>
                </div>

                <div id="collapse" class="collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                    <div class="card-block">
                    '.$name.'
                        <p> <strong> Time: </strong>'.$start_time.' - '.$end_time.' </p>
                        <p> <strong> Price: </strong>'.$price.' </p>
                        <p> <strong> Places available: </strong>'.$places.' </p>
                        <form action="" method = "post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'.$row["ID"].'" />
                            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name = "enroll" value = "Enroll">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        ';
    }

    echo '</div>';

}
```

**UPDATE**
To let the user select multiple courses you would need only 1 form with a checkbox array. Your `$_POST["ID"]` will be an array of class IDs. In the sample below it is stored serialized in your database, assuming `sectionID` is string. You could also `json_encode` the array before saving it to the database. If you want `sectionID` to be numeric you would need to create a new table to store all classes for each user.

```
if(array_key_exists("id", $_SESSION)) {

include("connection.php");

        if (array_key_exists("enroll", $_POST)) {
            $query = "UPDATE `users` SET sectionID = ".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, serialize($_POST["ID"]))." WHERE id = ".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_SESSION['id'])." LIMIT 1";

            mysqli_query($link, $query); 
        }


    $query = "SELECT * from `classes`";


    echo ' <form action="" method = "post">
          <div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true"> ';

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        $name = $row["name"];

        $start_time = $rows["begTime"];

        $end_time = $rows["endTime"];

        $price = $rows["price"];

        $places = $rows["placesAvailable"];



        echo '

            <div  class="card">
                <div id = "section" class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                            '.$name.'
                        </a>
                    </h5>
                </div>

                <div id="collapse" class="collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                    <div class="card-block">
                    '.$name.'
                        <p> <strong> Time: </strong>'.$start_time.' - '.$end_time.' </p>
                        <p> <strong> Price: </strong>'.$price.' </p>
                        <p> <strong> Places available: </strong>'.$places.' </p>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="ID[]" value="'.$row["ID"].'" />Enroll
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        ';
    }

    echo '</div>
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name = "enroll" value = "Submit">
    </form>';

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please give a hint how to implement the same thing but letting the user to enroll to several courses?